# Angularjs and Linkedin share

Tags: angularjs, linkedin-api

I have an angularjs website which contains several articles.

I want my users to be able to share their articles through the various social networks.

I'm using an angularjs plugin called `angularjs-socialshare`. Basically, the system makes a call to a sharing endpoint providing the url to be shared:

E.G.

`http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://www.google.com`

Now, since my content is loaded dynamically through angularjs, this would show something like `{{ description }}` and `{{ title }}`

To solve this problem, I have a phantomjs server that executes the javascript and serves a static html page to the bots. This is the htaccess I'm using to tell bots from requests (btw any tips here are welcome as well).

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|png|ico|ico)$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*pinterest.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*linkedin.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*slack.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*facebook.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*google.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*yahoo.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*bing.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:27366/$1 [P,L]
```

The `http://localhost:27366/$1` is just the phantomjs server.

Now, Facebook and Google both work fine. LinkedIn though doesn't, it either remains stuck on loading, or it displays just the url of the page.
I tried looking for some documentation, but every answer is referring old docs (which 404s ) and now I'm lost.

EDIT:

Sorry, I realized that the question didn't make much sense after re-reading it after a while. edited.

I wrote this question out of a little frustration, but I realize I should probably try to contact someone who works at linkedin to understand what's going on.

If I ever find a solution I'll make sure I update here for future reference

Comment: what is your actual question? how does *what* work? all you are showing here is an htaccess file, you aren't showing any code illustrating what you are trying to do.  are you using some sort of library, or making a query to an api? nothing here is obvious.

Comment: on the surface, this looks like it's more a question about phantomjs than about angular; there isn't any angular code presented at all.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging and fighting with support centers, I found out that basically some services (like LinkedIn, but there are others) do not work well with the hashbang.

I fixed this problem by switching to HTML5 mode (which removes the hashbang).

```
.config(function ($locationProvider) {
    if(window.history && window.history.pushState){ // Checks if browser has HTML5 support
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }
}
```

And also this in the head of my index page:

```
<base href="/">
```

Hope it helps someone